# Why some TCP sockets in Node.js take much more time to connect than most others?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I've created small lib `tcp-exists` to check if tcp endpoint exists. Just to iterate over a network to find anything on special ports.

[code of lib on github](https://github.com/JerryCauser/tcp-exists/blob/master/index.mjs)

But when I am iterating – some of tcp sockets (which creates by lib `tcp-exists`) take a large amount of time (1-3s instead of 5-20ms) to establish connections on 100% existing endpoints.

```js
import tcpExists from 'tcp-exists'

async function main () {
  for (let i = 1; i < 250; ++i) {
    let time = performance.now()
    const exists = await tcpExists('192.168.1.87', 80, 2000)
    time = performance.now() - time

    console.log(`time [${i}]:`, time)
    if (time > 500) console.log('=====STRANGE=====')
    if (!exists) console.log('exists')
  }
}

main()
```

There is no difference between am I checking the same port or different ports on one IP, or am I checking different IPs. Some of that connections will take x100 more time to establish a connection. It can lead to a situation when there is an endpoint that exists, but the function will return `false` because of a small timeout.

I cannot set a timeout bigger than 25ms for one check. Because if I will want to scan from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 (65536 endpoints) — where are most of IP has no endpoint and should be returned `false` by timeout — and use for example 1s as timeout - then it will take 65536 seconds or ~18hours...

Comment: Use Wireshark.  You'll likely find that the extra time comes from hosts not responding to you right away.  Also, if you want to make a port scanner, you don't need full TCP connections.  See also:  https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/featured/common-basic-port-scanning-techniques/

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to the same IP/port 250 times in a row?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is a simple example to replicate the problem

Answer (score -1):

The TCP handshake means that the client sends a SYN to the server, the server ACKs the clients SYN and send its own SYN back (usually both within a single packet, i.e. SYN+ACK) and then the clients reacts to the servers SYN with its own ACK. The speed of the handshakes thus depends on the network latency between client and server and how fast the server reacts to the connection request (SYN). Any packets lost on the way need to be retransmitted after some timeout, which further increases the time for the TCP handshake.

All of this is out of control of the client, i.e. there is no way to speed it up. High performance scanners therefore don't try one connection after the other but try many connections in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about paralleling connections, I'll try it, but still, it is not the answer. I'm really interested in why something like that happens. Why do some socket connections periodically (sometimes every 24 connections, sometimes every 75 connection) take x50-x100 times to connect? That is something about node sockets or maybe it depends on the OS or it is documented somewhere?

Comment: @JerryCauser: Larger changes in connect time to the same host a usually caused by packet loss. Such loss is only detected after a timeout and then the packet is retransmitted, which significantly increases the connection time. Packet loss might be caused by glitches at the physical layer and especially wireless connections are affected by this. It might be caused by network overload, like some other device on the network sending lots of data so that the router/switch cannot keep up with all packets. It might be caused by the receiving device dropping packets to limit potential attacks.

Comment: 1) Wireless - no. I've tested it also with wired connections - nothing changes.
2) Router - no. I've tested on the same machine - just changed latency normal connections.
3) I've tested it with several devices pi4-8gb, macbook, router keenetic ultra, router mikrotik, router tp-link. Troubles repeating. Only when I'm trying to check 8.8.8.8:53 - everything works as expected, but there is a latency ~45ms between requests, not 1-2ms .

Comment: @JerryCauser: All of the details you currently provide are relevant to debug your specific problem. They should have been in the question from start so that one could have provided a less generic answer than I gave. Please include the details and any more details you might have to your question instead of just providing them in a comment to a generic answer.

Comment: I'll add that info in question, but did you try my code example to replicate the trouble? Or just say "that packet loss trouble" and paste info about how TCP works (what I've already known)? Just if you tried it then everything become obvious without my comments.

Comment: @JerryCauser: Your code example assumes connection to a specific IP address. I was on the assumption that this IP address is not local, so there are several effects I mentioned which might impact the connectivity to this IP. Since I don't have the same setup of the network and not devices behaving the same way as you have I did not find it relevant to check the code out.